# Vue-chart-js data retrieval from API doesn't render BarChart

Tags: vue-chartjs

Using vue-chartjs my chart doesnt get rendered.
I have the following JSON structure coming from my API:

```
[{"source_ip":"xxx","event_count":203},{"source_ip":"xxx","event_count":33},{"source_ip":"xxx","event_count":23},{"source_ip":"xxx","event_count":16}
```

Following the example of the wiki (https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data)
what i did was creating the following Vue component and used it in my app.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Bar v-if="loaded" :data="chartData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  data: () => ({
    loaded: false,
    chartData: null,
    labels: ['source_ip','event_count']
  }),
  async mounted () {
    this.loaded = false

    try {
      const { data } = axios.get('/api/firewall_deny_untab')
      .then(function (response){return response.data})
      this.chartdata = data

      this.loaded = true
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The chart doesn't get rendered, the console error is the following 'TypeError: data is null'.
Data is clearly not null since i can use the same axios function and get the expected data.
Any idea on why this wouldn't work? Documentation is not helpful.